# Insert nested records to mongo in reactive fashion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, flux, project-reactor

Trying to wrap my head around the reactor model and pipeline, I want to insert to mongo a couple of `Users`, then for each user I would like to insert several (10) `Offers`

My current implementation include inserting 3 users to the database, block and insert the offers (only for 1 user) in a somewhat backward way, like so

```
Flux.just(u1, u2, u3).flatMap(u -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(u)).blockLast();
Arrays.asList(u1, u2, u3).forEach(user -> {
        IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(new Offer(user)).subscribe());
    });
```

The first line run fine, but I get the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open

Of course I can bypass this by inserting for each user separately, I don't know why this exception was raised and appreciate an answer about this issue as well

My **main** question is how to write it in the most reactive way, should I need to block in order to populate the entity `Id` after insert or there is a better way?

The exact implementation of `User` and `Offer` doesn't really matter, it can be a any simple records, but here they are

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
}
```

...

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "offers")
public class Offer extends BaseEntity {

    private String title;

    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId user;

    public Offer(){
        this.title = "some title " + new Random().nextInt(10);
    }

    public Offer(User user){
        this();
        this.user = new ObjectId(user.getId());
    }

    public void setUser(String userId) {
        this.user = new ObjectId(userId);
    }
}
```

`reactiveMongoTemplate` is from **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive** `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories`

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out I was pretty close to the correct solution

```
Flux.just(u1, u2, u3).flatMap(u -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(u)).subscribe(u -> {
    Flux.range(0,10).flatMap(i -> reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(new Offer(u))).subscribe();
});
```

now the code is truly reactive and it can be seen on the database as well (records are inserted with random order)